# I can't find information about facial recognition in flutter Desktop

Tags: flutter, desktop, face-recognition, facial-identification

Does anyone know what I need to use facial recognition in Flutter Desktop? I can't find information, I barely managed to use the camera but I can't move forward from there

I would appreciate it if you could give me information on where I can start.